# Working of increment operator and document.write function

Tags: javascript

As we all know:

> i++ -> use i first and then increment it's value
>
> ++i -> increment i first and then use i's new value

But in the code below something different

```
var n=5;
for(i=n;i>=1;--i)
{
   console.log(i);//output:5 why?
    for(j=1;j<=n;++j)
    {
       document.write(j);
    }
document.write("\n");
}
```

Even though we are using predecrement operator why the vaule outputs 5 on the fist loop?
Also we are using new line after the completion of the innerLoop but it dont show up .What can be the reason behind this?Is it becoz on each loop document.write() running document.open() function?If yes ,In which context || conditions will document.write runs document.open() function?

Comment: Despite the title, this has nothing to do with `document.write()`.

Comment: @MattBall After the completion of the inner loop we dont get new line why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `++j` in `for(j=1;j<=n;++j)` occurs at the end of the `for` loop after the statements in the loop are executed so there is no difference in a `for` construct  between `++j` and `j++`.

You can think of your loop like this:

```
for(j=1;j<=n;)
{
   document.write(j);
   ++j;
}
```

As for the `console.log(i);//output:5 why?` question, that's because `5` is the initial value for `i` assign in `i=n`.

As for the `document.write('/n');`, HTML ignores newlines.  If you want a visible newline, then use a `<p>` or `<br>` or some other HTML construct that makes space.  newlines are ignored.

There is no difference between this HTML:

```
<span>This is some text</span>
```

and this HTML with newlines in it:

```
<span>
This is some text
</span>
```

Comment: why we dont get new line after the complition of inner loop

Comment: @Maizere - I added that to the end of my answer.  It's because HTML ignores newlines and other multi-whitespace.

Comment: @Maizere to be more specific, HTML doesn't ignore newlines (just wrap the thing in `<pre>` and see what happens) but web browsers draws newlines in HTML as a single space. Actually web browsers draws all whitespace (newlines, space and tabs) as a single space no matter how many newlines space and tabs you print. The `<pre>` tag or the CSS property `white-space` changes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> Also we are using new line after the completion of the innerLoop but it dont show up

Because a new line in HTML is `<br>`, not `\n` which is whitespace so doesn't create a new line (per the HTML spec).